# Space between two variable values ​in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two fields that were stored with values ​​through a faker gem. First Name and Last name fields. I took the value of these fields and stored it in two variables. I want to compare the name of this user in the logged area.
The first name and lastname in the logged area appears with space but in my validation when I concatenate these two values ​​I am not able to insert the space to validate against the logged area

```
############### my code ##############
@take_first_name = input_first_name.send_keys(Faker::Name.first_name).value
input_last_name.send_keys(Faker::Name.last_name)
@take_last_name = input_last_name.send_keys(Faker::Name.last_name).value

def logged_area
  
  fname_lname = @take_first_name + @take_last_name
  pp fname_lname
  take_user = view_user.text (logged area)
  expect(take_user).to eql (fname_lname)
 end

error:
   Reason:

      expected: "RustyDevonKubKoss"
           got: "RustyDevon KubKoss"

      (compared using eql?)
```

Comment: Why not just add the space? `@take_first_name + " " + @take_last_name` or `"{@take_first_name} #{@take_last_name}"`

Comment: _"​​I am not able to insert the space"_ – what did you try to insert the space? Or did you expect Ruby to insert a space automatically when concatenating two strings via a`+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the part with
`@take_first_name + @take_last_name`

you maybe can use it as string
`"#{@take_first_name} #{@take_last_name}"`